# I cannot get global variable from seperate file for Threading

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have two files; One creates a function that adds variables to threads.

```
def makeThread(xAMTLetter):
    global Name
    global Key
    global ID
    getInfoOnThread()

    xAMTLetter = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=())
    xAMTLetter.Name = "Thread3"
    xAMTLetter.Key = getThreadInfo.ThreadKey
    xAMTLetter.ID = getThreadInfo.ThreadID
    threadsList.append(xAMTLetter)
    threadsIDList.append(xAMTLetter.ID)
    threadsNameList.append(xAMTLetter.Name)
    threadsKeyList.append(xAMTLetter.Key)
```

My other file prints the info on it.

```
    xx = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=())

    getInfoOnThread()
    x.Name = "Thread1"
    x.Key = getThreadInfo.ThreadKey
    x.ID = getThreadInfo.ThreadID
    threadsList.append(x)
    threadsIDList.append(x.ID)
    threadsNameList.append(x.Name)
    threadsKeyList.append(x.Key)

    getInfoOnThread()
    xx.Name = "Thread2"
    xx.Key = getThreadInfo.ThreadKey
    xx.ID = getThreadInfo.ThreadID
    threadsList.append(xx)
    threadsIDList.append(xx.ID)
    threadsNameList.append(xx.Name)
    threadsKeyList.append(xx.Key)

    makeThread(xxx)

    x.start()
    xx.start()
    xxx.start()

    for index, thread in enumerate(threadsList):
        thread.join()

    print(f"Thread 1 info:\nName: {x.Name}\nKey: {x.Key}ID: {x.ID}\n")
    print(f"Thread 2 info:\nName: {xx.Name}\nKey: {xx.Key}ID: {xx.ID}\n")
    print(f"Thread 3 info:\nName: {xxx.Name}\nKey: {xxx.Key}ID: {xxx.ID}\n")
```

And I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Files/main.py", line 40, in <module>
    makeThread(xxx)
NameError: name 'xxx' is not defined
```

I have been trying to fix this, but I haven't programmed in python in a while. Any thoughts?

Comment: from the look of provided code, xxx is simply not defined ; )

Comment: You never define `xxx` but you try to reference it.

Comment: You seem to expect `makeThread` to somehow generate a variable referring to the new thread.  You absolutely cannot do that by passing a non-existent variable name to the function, you have to `return` the value from the function, and assign it to a variable at the call site - `xxx = makeThread()` perhaps.